# c# Process output unreadable pckimmo

Tags: c#, process, output

I have been trying to read process output for parsing morphological analysis. But I can't read pckimmo32.exe output.

```
public static string Problem1()
{
    ProcessStartInfo _startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    Process p = new Process();
    StringBuilder outputStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    string filePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"..\..\PC-KIMMO\pckimmo32.exe";
    var file = new FileInfo(filePath);

    p.StartInfo = _startInfo;
    _startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    _startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    _startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    _startInfo.WorkingDirectory = file.Directory.FullName;
    _startInfo.FileName = file.FullName;
    p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, eventArgs) => outputStringBuilder.AppendLine(eventArgs.Data);
    p.Start();
    p.BeginOutputReadLine();
    var myWriter = p.StandardInput;
    myWriter.AutoFlush = true;
    myWriter.WriteLine("synthesize kitap +Noun +A3sg +P2sg +Loc");
    myWriter.Close();

    p.WaitForExit();
    var output = outputStringBuilder.ToString();

    return output;
}

public static void Display(DataReceivedEventArgs nes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(nes.Data);
}
```

I can read another text exe file output.

```
public static string Problem2()
{
    ProcessStartInfo _startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    Process p = new Process();
    StringBuilder outputStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    string filePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"..\..\..\RTest\bin\debug\RTest.exe";
    var file = new FileInfo(filePath);

    p.StartInfo = _startInfo;
    _startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    _startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    _startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    _startInfo.WorkingDirectory = file.Directory.FullName;
    _startInfo.FileName = file.FullName;
    p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, eventArgs) => outputStringBuilder.AppendLine(eventArgs.Data);
    p.Start();
    p.BeginOutputReadLine();
    var myWriter = p.StandardInput;
    myWriter.AutoFlush = true;
    myWriter.Close();

    p.WaitForExit();
    var output = outputStringBuilder.ToString();

    return output;
}
```

`Problem2` Method is success read output, I want read output `Problem1` method.

I believe I am on the right track but just need a couple pointers.

[Test project on the github](https://github.com/byguro/ProcessTestCR)

Comment: pckimmo.exe have been use a error output for output. I can read output with errorinput.  (RedirectStandardError , ErrorDataReceived, BeginErrorReadLine)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
private string ReadProcessOutput(string fileName, TimeSpan waitTime, string args, string commandToEnter) // Command to enter in input window.
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting process: {0}", fileName);

    Process proc = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = fileName,
            Arguments = args,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        }
    };

    proc.Start();

    proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(commandToEnter);
    proc.WaitForExit((int)waitTime.TotalMilliseconds);

    if (proc.HasExited)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Process {0} exited with code {1}", fileName, proc.ExitCode);
        string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine("Process output: " + Environment.NewLine + output);

        return output;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I haven't been read pckimmo.exe output. You could be get result output ?

Comment: If the process pckimmo.exe writes to standard output, this will return this as a string.

Comment: I don't know pckimmo inner process, but I see command output when file is running. My Problem2 method is read standard output response. Did you look github project this case?

Comment: I've read the project at GitHub, but unfortunately I don't have the time right now to download/run it.

Comment: I think you're on the right track indeed. It's figuring out the difference between the two .exe processes, why one gives output and the other doesn't.

Comment: pckimmo.exe is console app, when I was start process It's not run and complete. Its wait input command. I want read this command outputs. [Running Process](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/170017/solving-problems-of-monitoring-standard-output-and) its run

Comment: I've modified to include an input command you can pass to the function. I've tried this with an interactive command line exe and it works, I think this might get you further towards a solution!

Comment: **NB: You might need to include \r\n with your command for Enter**

Comment: I found pckimmo.exe is result output with standard error. Problem related to exe. Thanks for help.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!